# I am unable to use saved cookies cy.session() in my 'it' block

Tags: javascript, cookies, cypress

I tried to use the saved session in the 'it' block, but it's opening the `"baseurl/index.php/dashboard"` so it means opening the login page afresh. I am trying to use the saved cookies to directly visit or use in another 'it' block.

```
import testdata from '../../fixtures/testdata.json'
describe('Example to demonstrate the use `each` in Cypress', function () {
    const loginPage = (username, password) => {
        cy.session([username, password], () => {
            cy.visit('/') // baseUrl: "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/"
            cy.get('#txtUsername').type(username)
            cy.get('#txtPassword').type(username)
            cy.get('#btnLogin').click()
        })
    }
    beforeEach('Loading test data', function () {
        loginPage(testdata.username, testdata.password)
    })
    it('Validating the Quick Launch menu', function () {
        cy.visit('/index.php/dashboard')
        cy.get('.quickLaungeContainer').each(($el, index) => {
            expect($el).to.contain(this.testdata.quickLaunch[index])
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The code looks like it should work, you have `username` twice instead of `password` but I assume that's a typo.

In case the cookie isn't set as expected you can add a `validate` function to help you debug the `cy.session()`

See Gleb's video [Use cy.session Command To Prepare Test Data But Only When Needed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SOn8NbZF4o&t=2s), about 4 minutes in is the TLDR point.

The idea is to use `validate()` to assert the condition you ***assume*** will be true after the `setup()` has run.

In this case, just want to check a cookie has been set on the domain. If it does not happen, the `setup()` tries again and if still not passing `validate()` the test fails.

It's also useful if one of your tests deliberately removes the cookie, then the next test will cause it to be re-fetched.

**testdata.json**

```js
{
  username: ...,
  password: ...,
  quicklaunch: [...],
  cookieName: 'orangehrmlive'  // check actual name in devtools
}
```

**Test**

```js
import testdata from '../../fixtures/testdata.json'

describe('Example to demonstrate the use `each` in Cypress', function () {
    const loginPage = (username, password) => {
        const setup = () => {
          cy.visit('/') // baseUrl: "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/"
          cy.get('#txtUsername').type(username)
          cy.get('#txtPassword').type(password)
          cy.get('#btnLogin').click()
        }
        const validate = () => {
          cy.getCookie(testdata.cookieName).should('exist')
        }
        cy.session([username, password], setup, {validate})
    }
    beforeEach('Loading test data', function () {
        loginPage(testdata.username, testdata.password)
    })
    it('Validating the Quick Launch menu', function () {
        cy.visit('/index.php/dashboard')
        cy.get('.quickLaungeContainer').each(($el, index) => {
            expect($el).to.contain(this.testdata.quickLaunch[index])
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: I am surprised, my code is running now. However I tried using above setup and validate methods but I am getting an error "cy.getCookie() must be passed a string argument for name." and I can't understand "testdata.domain". Please explain dear Fody

Comment: You probably don't have `testdata.domain` property in the fixture - I just threw that in as an example (since you already work with fixture testdata). But you can add the property to the fixture, or hard-code a string instead. Probably the domain is `orangehrmlive` - but check in devtools, under Application menu then in Cookies section, click on your URL and you want the `Name` property in the right panel.

Comment: Actually, after explaining that I realise `domain` is the wrong thing to call it. `cookieName` is better.